How to solve abstract class override maximum recursion depth issue?
I am creating a class that has abstract methods and overriding in sub classes.
MethodInterceptor class has a method named __getattribute__ that call before and after method in executing methods:
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC


class MethodInterceptor(object):

    @abstractmethod
    def before_execute(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def after_execute(self):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if hasattr(attr, '__call__'):
            def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
                self.before_execute()

                result = attr(*args, **kwargs)
                self.after_execute()
                return result

            return new_func
        else:
            return attr

Creating sub class:
class LoggerInterceptor(MethodInterceptor):
    # overriding abstract method
    def before_execute(self):
        print("before")

    def after_execute(self):
        print("after")

Worker class:
class Worker(LoggerInterceptor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "worker"

    def work(self):
        print(f"hi I am {self.name}")


c = Worker()
c.work()

But I am getting an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Projects/Pycharm/method_interceptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    c.work()
  File "/Users/xxx/Projects/Pycharm/method_interceptor.py", line 18, in new_func
    self.before_execute()
  File "/Users/xxx/Projects/Pycharm/method_interceptor.py", line 18, in new_func
    self.before_execute()
  File "/Users/xxx/Projects/Pycharm/method_interceptor.py", line 18, in new_func
    self.before_execute() 
  [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded


__getattribute__ intercepts every attribute lookup, including self.before_execute.

is there any solution?

Sure, just deal with the case that those methods are what's being looked up - hasattr(attr, '__call__') and name not in ('after_execute', 'before_execute'), for example.
